# Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I checked the other questions but none of them seem to address my issue.
I have two `suspend fun`s in my `HomeViewModel` and I'm calling them in my `HomeFragment` (with a spinner text parameter).

The two suspend functions in `HomeViewModel`:

```
suspend fun tagger(spinner: Spinner){
       withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
           val vocab: String = inputVocab.value!!
           var tagger = Tagger(
                   spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() + ".tagger"
           )
           val sentence = tagger.tagString(java.lang.String.valueOf(vocab))
           tagAll(sentence)
       }
    }


    suspend fun tagAll(vocab: String){
       withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
           if (inputVocab.value == null) {
               statusMessage.value = Event("Please enter sentence")
           }
           else {
               insert(Vocab(0, vocab))
               inputVocab.value = null
           }
       }
    }
```

and this is how I call them in the `HomeFragment`:

```
GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO) {
        button.setOnClickListener {
            homeViewModel.tagger(binding.spinner)
        }
    }
```

At `tagger` I get the error "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body". But it's already inside a global scope. How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But it's already inside a global scope.

The call to `button.onSetClickListener()` is in a launched coroutine from a `CoroutineScope`. However, the lambda expression that you are passing to `onSetClickListener()` is a separate object, mapped to a separate `onClick()` function, and *that* function call is not part of that coroutine.

You would need to change this to:

```kotlin
    button.setOnClickListener {
        GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO) {
            homeViewModel.tagger(binding.spinner)
        }
    }
```

BTW, you may wish to review [Google's best practices for coroutines in Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices), particularly ["The `ViewModel` should create coroutines"](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#viewmodel-coroutines).

Comment: Thank you so much again! And especially for the guide links